# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest retuning media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to send send image and text using multipart/form-data but always getting error code 415 (media type not supported). I want to send 7 parameters and one image. Can anyone help me out ?? If I am sending image in phonegap then its working fine but in iOS getting error.
here is my code

```
// set Content-Type in HTTP header

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=@"dfgsdgrtredsvcv6546regfdgfy54tregffd"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
//-- Convert string into URL
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:Server Url"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//-- Append data into post url using following method
//-- For Sending text

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"amount"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[textFieldAmount.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"amount is %@", textFieldAmount.text);


// add params (all params are strings)
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@\r\n\r\n", @"asset.JPG"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", @"asset.JPG"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// add image data
if (imgData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=asset.JPG\r\n", @"43543tgregfg4654654tre"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type:image\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imgData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR CONNECTING DATA FROM SERVER: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else
    {
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
        //success
        [self killHUD];
        NSLog(@"response is %@", response);
               }
    }`enter code here`
}];
```

Comment: It's not your code. The error is telling you the problem.

Comment: its not my code means ??? can you please elaborate ??